# Could not connect to host soap exception

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am using `SOAP` in a `php` script to call a web service from a `Linux Centos 6` server. In this week I have been getting `could not connect to host` error from soapCall method. Of course this exception does not happen all the time but I see this exception most of the time, for example if I call `soapCall` 5 times, this error happens 3 times.  My code is as below and I have not changed it at all for some months but recently it gets this error most of the time.

```
$wsdl="http://x.x.x.x:x/gw/services/Service?wsdl";

//Set key as HTTP Header 
$aHTTP['http']['header'] =  "key:" .$key ."\r\n";

$context = stream_context_create($aHTTP);

try
{
  $client = new SoapClient($wsdl,array("soap_version" => SOAP_1_2,'trace' => 1,"stream_context" => $context));
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        return "something";             
}
//I make $parametrs
try
{

 $res = $client->__soapCall("send",array($parametrs));
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    print_r($e->getMessage()); //Most of the time it prints could not connect to host
}
```

I have read most answers to related questions here but my problem has not been solved. Also I added

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_ttl","0");
```

but nothing changed. I searched a lot about the reason and I found something about `SSL` but I have not found exact solution.
It must be mentioned that I can see the `wsdl` URL in browser and I have it's ping.